# Reusing the same SVG in a PDF with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: python, html, webkit, svg, wkhtmltopdf

I have the following HTML for conversion to PDF using wkhtmltopdf:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<object data="first.svg" width="100" height="100" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
<object data="second.svg" width="100" height="100" type="image/svg+xml"></object> 
<object data="third.svg" width="100" height="100" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
</body>
</html>
```

I will be using these SVG files more than once, in multiple locations, for example one will be at the top of each page.

How can I have the outputted PDF file reuse the already existant SVGs else where in the document, without making a brand new one in the PDF, thus increasing the filesize.

Comment: Are you asking about having a PDF file load an external SVG file?
Even if you could do that, and I don't think you can, it is a bad idea.
The entire point of PDF files is that they're entirely self-contained.

Comment: when the web page gets converted into a pdf, the svg should be converted into native pdf vector code. This should be very lightweight. Not sure if that's how wkhtltopdf does it, but I would test it before you try to prematurely optimize.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with wkhtmltopdf, but the structure of a PDF file is that it contains a library of "glyphs" (corresponding to letters, symbols, digraphs, etc) that are reused over and over at different coordinates.

It seems very likely that you could turn the final svg image into a glyph, but I'm afraid I don't have any more detail than that to offer.

Answer (score 0):

Found this post looking for wkhtmltopdf support for vector graphics, and, on initial inspection it seems that there is a better way of embedding svg: the img tag with css width/height to constrain/set the size. Works beautifully...

I also tried including my svg more than once - the file size grows, and grows, and grows with each instance added.
At a guess it is a logo that you need adding to your pages. What you might want to consider is running the file through Pdftk and watermarking your pages:

http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/

Comment: It is a logo. Will passing this through pdftk reduce the file size by re-using the same SVG over and over?

Comment: As a watermark = same image on all pages that will be just the one object. It is part of the PDF spec, much like adding a watermark in Word - you haven't added the logo to every page, just the watermark that gets shown with every page.

Comment: Will this watermark push the content down? (For example used as a header). And can more than one watermark be used? I will have 2 - 3 different logos depending on the page, with the logo on the first page always being different to the rest. (The rest usually being the same)

Comment: I am not sure that the watermarking route is for your project as watermarking is across the whole document, and with PDFtk there is the option for that to be a 'stamp' (on top) or a 'background' (below your main content).
You could always try merging different PDF's if your frontpage has the logo in a different place.
The process should not push any content on your pages.

You may want to have a play with the graphical frontend and see if you can achieve what you want with the GUI, if that is do-able then you can get it working in a script file. See: 
http://pdfchain.sourceforge.net/